# Prove that $\{x \mid(1+n)^{x}\equiv1+nx \pmod{n^2}\}=\{x \mid x^n\equiv 1\pmod{n^2}\}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, cryptography

We have $n=pq$, with $p,q$ two different odd prime numbers.

I must prove that :

$A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \mid  (1+n)^{x}\equiv1+nx \pmod{n^2}\}=\{x\in (\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^{\times}  \mid  x^n\equiv 1\pmod{n^2}\}=B$.

Notice that $(1+n)^x \equiv 1+nx \pmod {n^2}$ and #$B=n=pq=$#$A$.

Maybe if I prove one inclusion and with equality of cardinality it will be fine.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand $(1+n)^x$ where the base is a positive integer but the exponent $x$ is a congruence class. How do you define this?

Comment: Sorry for my typo mistake

Comment: Sorry for my obtuseness. I should have realized you made a simple typo and corrected it.

Comment: Your $(1+x)^n\equiv1+nx (\mod n^2)$ is false. For example, take $n=6$. Only $x=0$ satisfies the congruence. Why  did you think it was true?

Comment: @Somos sorry I just re-saw the statement and it's $(1+n)^x$

Comment: Then we are back to square one. Still $(1+n)^x$ doesn't make sense because the exponent is a conguence class. Please check the source of this problem. Did you copy it correctly? Your first notice statement is still false if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: @Somos if you apply the binomial formula it will work.

Comment: The binomial formula I am familiar with is $(a+b)^n = a^n+...+b^n$ with $n$ a non-negative integer. A residue class is not a non-negative integer so it doesn't apply here. Also, my example in a previous comment for $n=6$ disproves your first notice statement. You have to be careful not to apply formulas blindly. There are often conditions which have to be satisfied. One simple example is $x/x=1$ except if $x=0$. A common mistake is to forget to ensure that $x$ is nonzero.

Comment: @Somos The congruence $(1+n)^x\equiv 1+nx\pmod{n^2}$ for $x\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ does indeed make sense. In particular, one can check that both expressions $(1+n)^x\pmod{n^2}$ and $1+nx\pmod{n^2}$ are unchanged if $x$ is replaced by a different representative of its residue class (mod $n$), that is, if $x$ is replaced by $x+nk$.

Comment: @Maman The definition of $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \colon (1+n)^{x}=1+nx\}$ doesn't seem to make sense, since the values of $(1+n)^{x}$ and $1+nx$ do definitely depend on which representative of $x$'s residue class you choose. Do you mean something like $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \colon (1+n)^{x}\equiv 1+nx \pmod{n^3}\}$?

Comment: Okay, I am surprised that I didn't check, but you are right. I should have known that $(1+n)^x$ is periodic $\mod n^2$ and it is clear that $1+n x$ is also. I now see that my objections are overcome. Still, there was a bit of information missing in the original statement of the problem to justify it.

Comment: I now recall how this relates to the multiplicative group of $p$-adic integers and $p$-adic logarithms. Not the kind of knowledge that comes to my mind immediately but it is very relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem was not clear enough as stated.
Here is one attempt at proof. The ring of integers
 $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$
has a multiplicative subgroup of elements
 $\{1+nx \mid x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\}$.
Because it is cyclic with generator $1+n$ and of order $n$,
this is the same as $B$. The multiplication on the subgroup is
$(1+nx)(1+ny)=1+n(x+y)$ and $(1+n)^x=1+nx$ expresses each
element using the generator $(1+n)$. Thus, the additive group
$A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative
subgroup $B$. Thus $\#B=\#A$. The reason why this works is that $n$ is the product of distinct odd primes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The statement has a link with Paillier's cyphering. It was not explicit I changed the set $A$.